# Problem with linux kernel configuration during update operation

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, updates, dpkg

During the update operation I got the following error:

```
(Reading database ... 713992 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-extra-4.10.0-35-generic (4.10.0-35.39~16.04.1) ...
depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.10.0-35-generic: No such file or directory
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.0-35-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-35-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.10.0-35-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-35-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.10.0-35-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-35-generic
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-35-generic
Warning: No support for locale: en_IN
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_XGKldO/lib/modules/4.10.0-35-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_XGKldO/lib/modules/4.10.0-35-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-35-generic with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.10.0-35-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-extra-4.10.0-35-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried to purge the kernel that causes the problem with no success. How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is `gzip: stdout: No space left on device`. If the file system is full and parts of the package can't be extracted, any strange errors may follow.

Clean your system to free space.

Comment: I think the space is not an issue here, because more than 15 GB of free space is there .

Comment: When it says `no space left` it is an issue. Not neccessary your root device, maybe the `/boot` volume. Check your `df`

Comment: Yup! I got the point. There were 9 additional kernels installed in the system.  Many thanks @Philippos.

Comment: You have to run `sudo apt autoremove` every now and then after doing upgrade. `sudo apt upgrade` tells you every time which packages, including kernels, that should be removed with autoremove.